# Создание фала "на лету"

Tags: python

есть программа в которой происходит инициализация базы данных SQLite, если файл с БД уже есть, то просто происходит коннект, а если нет - создание файла БД, но пока программа не завершит свою работу, то файл не появится в системе, как можно решить этот вопрос, я думал что можно вынести эту функцию в отдельный поток, но увы, это не сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где-нибудь в начале программы

```
from contextlib import closing
import sqlite3

with closing(sqlite3.connect('example.db')) as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table (...)')
    conn.commit()
```

А дальше работайте с базой как обычно.

Comment: ммм.  а зачем "import closing"?

Comment: @vitidev использование контекстных менеджеров для управления ресурсами - это полезная привычка, но `sqlite3.connect()` сам этот интерфейс не реализует.